# svn with redmine error.log apache Permission denied

Tags: apache, http, svn, redmine

I try to access from redmine to my svn repository. When I write  http url in the browser I access the svn but since redmine I have this error.

> Can't check path
>   '/var/svn/projet/db/locks/666/6666cd76f96956469e7be39d750cc7d9':
>   Permission denied  [500, #13]

The locks folder does not exist.I work with docker redmine run in container and the svn in other container.

**Update 28 JUL 2017**

Configuration nginx:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name  svn.domaine.com;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://172.18.0.1:1200;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    }
}
```

When i access

> http:// svn.domaine.com/projet

i get revisions. But on redmine which is on the same machine

> http:// 172.18.0.1:1200/projet

i get 404 and apache return this error:

> Can't check path
>   '/var/svn/projet/db/locks/666/6666cd76f96956469e7be39d750cc7d9':
>   Permission denied [500, #13]

Comment: most likely there is a problem with a fact how your repository is accessed, is it thru http or you tried thru filesystem?

Comment: I updated ticket